# Only show the FAQ answer related to the clicked question

Tags: javascript, html

I want only display one answer when I click on a question, but all answers are being shown.

```js
let ques = document.querySelectorAll(".question")
let ans = document.querySelectorAll(".answer")

ques.forEach((question) => {
  question.addEventListener("click", () => {
    ans.forEach((answer) => {
      answer.classList.toggle("display")
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none;
}

.answer.display {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue in your code is because you're looping through all the `.answer` elements, not the one related to the clicked `.question`.

To do what you need you can use `closest()` and `querySelector()` to find the `.answer` within the same parent as the `.question` which was clicked and toggle the `display` class on it. You can then loop through all other `.answer` elements and remove the `display` class from them.

Here's a working example:

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question");
const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");

questions.forEach(q => {
  q.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const answer = q.closest('.faq').querySelector('.answer');
    answer.classList.toggle('display');  
    answers.forEach(a => a != answer && a.classList.remove("display"))
  })
})
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none;
}

.answer.display {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using an [adjacent css sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) and [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Now you only have to manipulate the `active` class on the `.question` element to show the right answer.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList?.contains(`question`)) {
    document.querySelector(`.active`)?.classList.remove(`active`);
    return evt.target.classList.add(`active`);
  }
}
```

```css
.question {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.question + .answer {
  display: none;
}

.question.active + .answer {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answer">answer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only shows the answers on hover while the question was showing them on click. If they want it on click then they will need scripting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want the click function to show the answer not with the hover action.

Comment: Yeah, sorry @UmeshSingh, bad reading from my side. Changed the answer.

Comment: No need for return on `evt.target.classList.add('active');`

Comment: @mplungjan It won't not hurt either.

Comment: Sure. But it might stick around until it will

Comment: >  it might stick around until it will 
Anything in life does so, right? No worries.

Comment: "No need for return ..." BTW, I use return by default to [avoid if-else](https://medium.com/swlh/stop-using-if-else-statements-f4d2323e6e4)

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and with delegated event handling

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', e =>
  e.target.closest('.faq .question')?.
    nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('display'));
```

Explanation: When someone clicks the body find out if a question was clicked, and if so get its next sibling (the answer) and toggle its display class.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate from the nearest static container - it is never useful to add an eventListener to many identical elements in the same container.

Use hidden for simplicity. Alternatively use `classList.toggle("display",tgt.nextElementSibling === answer)`

```js
const container = document.getElementById("faqContainer");
const answers = container.querySelectorAll(".answer");
container.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".question");
  if (!tgt) return; // not a question
  answers.forEach(answer => answer.hidden = tgt.nextElementSibling !== answer);
});
```

```html
<div id="faqContainer">
  <div class="faq">
    <div class="question">question 1</div>
    <div class="answer" hidden>answer 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq">
    <div class="question">question 2</div>
    <div class="answer" hidden>answer 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq">
    <div class="question">question 3</div>
    <div class="answer" hidden>answer 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching listeners to all the elements wrap the FAQ sections in a container, add *one* listener to that (this is known as [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)), and catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM.

If the element clicked on is a question you can toggle the display class on its [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling).

You can cache the answer elements and then iterate over them with `forEach` in the handler.

```js
const faqs = document.querySelector('.faqs');
const answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');

faqs.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.question')) {
    answers.forEach(a => a.classList.remove('display'));
    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('display');
  }
}
```

```css
.faq { margin: 0.5rem 0; }
.question:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.answer { padding: 0.25rem; display: none; background-color: lightblue; }
.display { display: block; }
```

```html
<section class="faqs">
  <section class="faq">
    <h3 class="question">Question 1</h3>
    <p class="answer">Answer 1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="faq">
    <h3 class="question">Question 2</h3>
    <p class="answer">Answer 2</p>
  </section>
  <section class="faq">
    <h3 class="question">Question 3</h3>
    <p class="answer">Answer 3</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Apart from the fancy colours, this is really very close to what I posted, no?

Comment: Imagine that. Two seasoned developers coming up with similar approaches. I don't pay attention to what other people have written while I'm working on my own answer.

Comment: I understand. It was just weird since your answer was 15 minutes later than several delegation answers. No problem